# AWS CloudFormation: Resize a Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

How to resize the redshift cluster using cloudformation and keep the cluster name?
Is there an example?

Comment: I don't have an example of this and I'm interested in see such an example as well.  I will pass on some advice - test any solution for side effects before any mission critical impacts are felt.  I had a client use CF to make WLM changes to their cluster and this caused a database reboot even though no reboot was required for the WLM change.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the user guide of the [AWS::Redshift::Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html), you will find a property called [NumberOfNodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html). The last line of its declaration is important if you intend to modify the property:

> Update requires: [No interruption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html#update-no-interrupt)

If you follow that link you will find that:

> AWS CloudFormation updates the resource without disrupting operation of that resource and without changing the resource's physical ID

Consequently, you can change the size of the cluster in the cloud formation template, submit it (either using the AWS console or the AWS CLI) and the cluster will be resized accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation.

Thanks a lot for the help.